# How to work with async-await within a for-each loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm working on a project where there is an array that I need to go through and query a model from my MongoDB database.

After this query is done, I need to increment another array with the query response, but after I query using await, everything under the query seems to be 'ignored'.

I've tried to return a promise, or even use .then () but nothing works.

```
const schedules = { all: [], unique: [], final: []};
...
schedules.unique.forEach(async (schedule) => {
const final = await ScheduleRef.findById(schedule);
  schedules.final.push(final);
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/3163075

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're correct that `findById` returns a promise, you should be able to gather all the promises together by iterating over `schedules.unique` with `map`, and then assigning the value of the `await`ed `Promise.all` to `schedule.final`.

```js
const schedules = { all: [], unique: [], final: []};

(async () => {
  const finds = schedules.unique.map(schedule => {
    return ScheduleRef.findById(schedule);
  });
  schedules.final = await Promise.all(finds);
})();
```